# Nativescript plugin including an Android SDK instead of an aar

Tags: android, sdk, nativescript, aar

I have problems integrating an external android sdk.

I was able to make a nativescript plugin using an aar but when I want to put a sdk in its place it does not work.

The structure of the plugin is as follows

**(This does work)**

```
plugin/
    platforms/
        android/
            libs/
               toasterlibrary-release.aar
            Manifest.xml
   index.js
   package.json
```

**(This doesn't work)**

```
plugin/
    platforms/
        android/
            libs/
               toaster-library.apk
               output.json
            Manifest.xml
   index.js
   package.json
```

**( index.js )**

```
var application = require("application");
var context = application.android.context;

module.exports = {
    showToast: function() {        
        var toaster = new com.example.toasterlibrary.ToasterMessage();
        console.log(toaster.show(context,"Prueba de toast"));
    }
};
```

The error is launched in the index.js  when try to use toasterlibrary

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'toasterlibrary' of undefined
```

I do not know what to do differently to include an apk in place of an aar

Comment: What is `toaster-library.apk`, that doesn't sound like a SDK. It should be a JAR / AAR, you cannot include a prebuilt APK.

Comment: Thanks you for your response.